# are there any design patterns to deal with the two models and same database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

i'm blocked at this level, i have a model as shown in the picture, i want to use one single database table for both validated and notValidated documents, since the same document can have an association with both of the models.[class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8HML.png)
neither STI nor polymorphic associations are solution to this issue.
so the question is how can i manage in rails, to create two models but one database table for it, is there a design pattern that goes this way ?.

For example :

```
document { id: 1, added_by: user1}
document_not_validated { duration_estimated: 12}
document_validated { duration_after_validation: 10, added_by: super_user}.
```

So all these data could be in one line in the DB table, but i need different models (setting the table name is not the solution i look for neither)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a column 'validated' with boolean true/false value?

Comment: The example i gave is quiet simple, to make it easier to understand what  need.
The problem is to get an object of each type ( validated and not validated document) without getting each time all the attributes, even if it is validated i will still need the data of the non_vlidated_document, adding a column is not what i look for.
thanks